# Is there a way to control thread count, affinity and creation time in Intels Threading Building Blocks?

Tags: c++, multithreading, tbb

Currently I use Intels TBB to parallelize some work using tbb::parallel_for. It seems that the amount of threads and the point in time when they are started is controlled by TBB in the background. Looking through the User Guide and Reference Documentation I could not find any hint on whether there are any control options or modules.
I would like to be able to modify the amount of threads and, if possible, decide when the thread pool is created.

**Edit:** 
Why it is nice to control the thread count: The program is designed to run on our cluster system and on those of our users. Since processing time is not always available exlusively to one user it is a nice feature

Question: Can you explain why you need more control over when the threads start?
Answer: Multithreading via TBB is used in many places and since some people fear "overhead" I have been tasked to figure out a way to start the threads only once.

Comment: How to set the number of threads: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3786408/56778

Comment: Can you explain why you need more control over when the threads start?  The TBB threads sleep while they are not in use.

Answer (score 0):

This might help - I've never actually used TBB but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786408/number-of-threads-used-by-intel-tbb?lq=1) seem to be what you are asking.

"When you create the scheduler, you can specify the number of threads as

```
tbb::task_scheduler_init init(nthread);
```

else you can use

```
tbb::task_scheduler_init init(tbb::task_scheduler_init::automatic);
```

In this case, tbb scheduler creates as many threads as your CPU cores."